# How do I pull the resource title from a FrameworkElement at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf

Given the following XAML:

```xml
 <Label  Foreground="White" FontSize="24" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="{DynamicResource  DOB}"/>
```

I would like to pull the string "DOB" from the Content property and append a value at runtime, for example, "DOB_1" (to pull the resource key DOB_1).

How do I do this?

Comment: This reeks of horrible design.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You're asking for a very specific solution, while something else might better suit your needs.

Comment: I am simply inquiring if the binding expression might be retrieved at runtime.

Comment: Retrieving a binding expression at runtime would be no problem, this however is not a binding expression.

Comment: I'm asking why do you want to do that? Is is just out of curiosity or are you trying to achieve something? If you are, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic resources work with `ResourceReferenceExpressions` which is an internal class, this is not going to work.